# Android Studio can't find JVM

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio

I am trying to use Android Studio after working with Eclipse without problems.

I am using Windows 7 SP1 64-Bit

However when I try to start Android Studio, I get the following error message:

> The environment variable JAVA_HOME (with the value of C:\Program Files\IBM\Java80) does not point to a valid JVM installation)

I have been working with that Java installation for a while, and I am not sure what to do. I have tried reinstalling Java and installing a more recent version. It works fine under Eclipse but Android Studio does not even start.

java -version returns the following:

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pwa6480sr2-20151023_01(SR2))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.8, JRE 1.8.0 Windows 7 amd64-64 Compressed References 2015101
9_272764 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R28_Java8_SR2_20151019_2144_B272764
JIT  - tr.r14.java_20151006_102517.04
GC   - R28_Java8_SR2_20151019_2144_B272764_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20151019_272764)
JCL - 20151022_01 based on Oracle jdk8u65-b17
```

Comment: is C:\Program Files\IBM\Java80 the correct path to your jdk? so your java.exe is found under C:\Program Files\IBM\Java80\bin\?

Comment: Yes. The bin is found there with all the files. That path has been working with eclipse and java applications for a while.

Comment: any specific reason why you are using the ibm sdk and not the standard jdk from oracle? have you tried it with that already?

Comment: I have to use the IBM sdk as per company policy. I have not tried the oracle sdk yet. I doubt that it is a specific problem with the ibm sdk though, as Android Development in eclipse works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure the JDK is installed? The JRE is not enough.

Comment: well if you are so sure, then...
But i think otherwhise. My guess is, that you have to run Android Studio(or IDEA) on the oracle JDK. If you do that, you still can use the IBM sdk for compiling and running your projects (what is what you want).

Comment: try the command : C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>javac -version, you will see if you have a JDK in you JAVA_HOME directory or not.

Answer (score 0):

JRE (Java Runtime Environment) isn't enough. Android Studio is for development, **you need the development kit**:

- **JDK** (Java Development kit)
- **SDK** (Software development kit)

Try this command to know if you have a development kit in IBM package :

```
C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>javac -version
```

If this command isn't recognize, install one of these :

- IBM® SDK, Java™ Technology Edition, Version 8 : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/java8/
- Anroid SDK :
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply the command returns the following
`C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN>javac -version
javac 1.7.0-internal`